# angularjs design. calling a directive function from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, angularjs-directive

I have the following code http://plnkr.co/edit/3WRDCv?p=preview
I have a directive that can perform cropping on an image via canvas. My project has a state `crop-image` with a controller `cropController` and the template has a button in the header. I would like to perform a function within my directive when I press the header button. How do I do this? I've been told I should use an isolated scope somehow or create a service object, no clue.

**canvas-directive.js**

```
'use strict';
app.directive('myCanvas', function() {
return {

restrict: 'E',
replace: true,
template: '<div><canvas id="source"></canvas><canvas id="copyCanvas"></canvas></div>',

// setup two cavases. load original image in one, determine dimensions of 
// the display and render fitted image in the other canvas
link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
  console.log('inside directive imageURI: ' + $scope.imageURI);

  var canvasSource = $element[0].children[0];
  var ctxSource = canvasSource.getContext('2d');
  var canvasCopy = $element[0].children[1];
  var copyContext = canvasCopy.getContext('2d');
  $('#copyCanvas').hide();

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = $scope.imageURI;
  var ratio = 0;
  img.onload = function() {
    console.log('img:',img, img.width, img.height);
    console.log('screen:', screen.width, screen.height);
    console.log('$(window) :', $(window).height(), $(window).width());

    $scope.maxWidth = $(window).width();
    $scope.maxHeight = $(window).height();

    if(img.width > $scope.maxWidth) {
      ratio = $scope.maxWidth / img.width;
    }
    else if(img.height > $scope.maxHeight) {
      ratio = $scope.maxHeight / img.height;
    }
    else {
      ratio = $scope.maxWidth / img.width;
    }

    canvasCopy.width = img.width;
    canvasCopy.height = img.height;
    copyContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    canvasSource.width = img.width * ratio;
    canvasSource.height = img.height * ratio;
    ctxSource.drawImage(canvasCopy,
      0, 0, canvasCopy.width, canvasCopy.height,
      0, 0, canvasSource.width, canvasSource.height);

    function showCoords(c) {
      // variables can be accessed here as
      // c.x, c.y, c.x2, c.y2, c.w, c.h
      console.log(c.y, c.y2, c.h);
      $scope.dy1 = c.y;
      $scope.dy2 = c.y2;
    }
    $('#source').Jcrop({
      onSelect: showCoords,
      onChange: showCoords,
      bgColor: '#BFAC9E',
      bgOpacity: 0.4,
      setSelect: [0, 50, canvasSource.width, canvasSource.height * 0.8],
      minSize: [ canvasSource.width, 30]
    });

    $scope.cropImage = function() {
    console.log('button press registered in directive!');
    crop(0, $scope.dy1, $scope.maxWidth, $scope.dy2);
  }

    $scope.crop = function(x, y, xDif, yDif) {
    canvasSource.width = xDif;
    canvasSource.height = yDif;
    $('#source').css('height', yDif/ratio);
    $('.jcrop-holder').css('height', yDif/ratio);
    $('.jcrop-holder div').hide();
    ctxSource.drawImage(img, x, y, xDif, yDif, 0, 0, xDif, yDif);

    croppedImg = canvasSource.toDataURL();
    //document.getElementById('output').src = croppedImg;
    //window.location = "/show-image/" + encodeURIComponent(croppedImg);
    //window.location.href = croppedImg.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  }
  };
},
//scope: {
//  control: '='
//},

// expose api for cropping images
controller: function($scope) {

}
};
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button is outside of the directive's scope, which I'm assuming is the case, then you will need to have that button send a message that the directive's controller is listening for. If your directive is inside of the element that your header controller is scoped to, then `$scope.$broadcast` should work; otherwise you'll need to `$broadcast` from the `$rootScope`:

```
$scope.buttonClick = function() {
    $scope.$broadcast('button clicked');
});
```

Then in your directive:

```
$scope.$on('button clicked', function() {
    // Do something now that the button is clicked.
});
```

Comment: very cool this answered my question. Now how do I tell my controller to wait until the directive is done cropping before doing more things? I need to initiate a state transition once the image is cropped.

Comment: Same thing but reverse. Broadcast a message from the directive when it's done its thing, and have the controller listen for it.

Comment: wow cool. I was looking into returning a promise instead. Which is better?

Comment: Two different things. You could use a promise if you want but you'd still some way for two decoupled scopes/controllers to communicate back and forth.